# React: tracking history changes by history.push in common component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Layout component which wraps the rest of my application. The default route is a page with multiple buttons, implemented as a small component called NavButton, which use `history.push` to go to a new route. Then in my Layout component, there are 2 buttons, but one of them should change depending on which route we are currently navigated to. So when we are on the main page, the button should say i.e. "Change Code", but on any other page, it should say "Back". I tried it in the following way:

Layout.tsx:

```
interface ILayoutProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const Layout: React.FC<ILayoutProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const currentRoute = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(currentRoute);
  }, [currentRoute]);

  const logout = () => {
    console.log('logout');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{children}</div>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          {currentRoute.pathname === '/' ? (
            <NavButton displayName="Change Code" route="/change-code" variant="outlined" />
          ) : (
            <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" fullWidth>
              Back
            </Button>
          )}
        </Grid>
        ...
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

NavButton.tsx:

```
interface NavButtonProps {
  displayName: string;
  route: string;
  variant?: 'text' | 'outlined' | 'contained';
}

const NavButton: React.FC<NavButtonProps> = ({ displayName, route, variant = 'contained' }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const navigatePage = () => {
      history.push(route);
      // Also tried it like this:
      // setTimeout(() => history.push(route), 0);
  };

  return (
    <Button
      variant={variant}
      color="primary"
      onClick={() => navigatePage()}
      fullWidth
    >
      {displayName}
    </Button>
  );
};

export default NavButton;
```

SO in my Layout, I am trying to keep track of location changes with the `useLocation()` hook, but when a button is pressed, and thus `history.push(route)` is called, it doesn't get detected by the hook in Layout. I've also tried to use the `useHistory()` hook and call the `listen()` method on it, but same problem. Also, my router is a BrowserRouter, not sure if that is of any help... What am I missing here?

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a codesandbox and I see the location log in the effect in `Layout` when navigating. I also implemented the history listener there as well and see the `location` and navigation method log out. Can you create a *running* codesandbox of *your* code that reproduces the issue you see?

Comment: Okay, trying to get it working on a sandbox made me realise what the issue was. I kept getting errors for invalid hook call, because I was using Layout as a wrapper around my Router, while it actually needed to be a child of my Router. Making that change, I got it working.

Comment: Yup, that'll do it alright. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that I had my App component defined like this:

```
<Layout>
    <Routes />
</Layout>
```

And my Routes looked like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route ...>
        ....
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The `useLocation()` hook in my Layout wasn't working since it was not a child of my BrowserRouter. Changing it to be like that made the code work.

Only thing I find weird is that in my app, I didn't get an error for invalid hook call, but in the sandbox I did. Maybe I need to upgrade my React packages...

Comment: If you haven't upgraded to more recent versions of CRA/react-scripts, then you can try manually adding the [ESLint Plugin - eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin).